# inserting unique elements from std::vector to std::set

Tags: c++, stl

I have a class called `Point`, used to store x and y double values. I have a `std::vector` of `Point`s that contain duplicate values. I am trying to count the number of unique items in this vector.

I thought since `std::set` only unique objects, creating a `set` from `vector` would give me unique values. But I am not getting the right results. I have overloaded the equality operator. But still the duplicate values gets inserted into the `set`.

the current results are like below..

```
10,10 repetitions - 1
10,10 repetitions - 1
20,20 repetitions - 1
20,20 repetitions - 1
```

I am expecting...

```
10,10 repetitions - 2
20,20 repetitions - 2
```

Any clues where I am wrong? Complete code is below.

**Point.h file**

```
#ifndef POINT_H
#define POINT_H
class Point
{
public:
    Point(double x, double y);
    double getX();
    double getY();

    Point(const Point &other);

    bool operator == (const Point& p );
    bool operator != (const Point& p );

private:
    double _x;
    double _y;
};
#endif // POINT_H
```

**Point.cpp file**

```
#include "point.h"

Point::Point(double x, double y)
{
    _x = x;
    _y = y;
}

Point::Point(const Point &other)
{
    _x = other._x;
    _y = other._y;
}

double Point::getX()
{
    return _x;
}

double Point::getY()
{
    return _y;
}

bool Point::operator == ( const Point& p )
{
    return ( (_x  == p._x ) && (_y == p._y));
}

bool Point::operator != ( const Point& p )
{
    return !((*this) == p );
}
```

**main.cpp file**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include "Point.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    std::vector <Point*> pointsVector;
    pointsVector.push_back(new Point(10,10));
    pointsVector.push_back(new Point(10,10));
    pointsVector.push_back(new Point(20,20));
    pointsVector.push_back(new Point(20,20));


    std::set<Point*> uniqueSet( pointsVector.begin(), pointsVector.end() );

    std::set<Point*>::iterator it;
    for (it = uniqueSet.begin(); it != uniqueSet.end(); ++it)
    {
        Point* f = *it; // Note the "*" here
        int result = std::count( pointsVector.begin(), pointsVector.end(), f );
        cout << f->getX() << "," << f->getY() << " repetitions - " << result << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @LuchianGrigore since he wants a recount about how many time each unique element appears in the vector an std::map will do this automatically for you, the element will be the key - first value - and the counter will be value -second value .

Comment: @user1824407 - will it work for collection of pointers?

Comment: @vinayan no, but you still haven't told us why you need pointers.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - I was just looking at how it would be with pointers..now i am trying to make it objects and i am getting the < operator not overloaded error..so i will have to follow your answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All your elements are different because you:

1) use pointers, so you'll have to pass a custom comparator that compares pointers to `Point` taking into account what they point to.

2) assume `std::set` uses `operator ==` or `operator !=` when in fact it uses `operator <`.

I would have a collection of `Point` instead of `Point*`. Do you have any reason to use pointers instead of objects? If not, then use objects.

Comment: thanks..i am yet to get a hang on pointers and c++ in general..so what would a custom comparator look like? should i also be overloading operator < ?

Comment: @vinayan for an example, see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/functional/less/ which is the default used. It calls `operator <`, but for a container of pointers, it just compares pointers.

Comment: @vinayan You don't have to use pointers: just do `Point p1(10, 10), p2(10, 10), p3(20, 20), p4(20, 20)` and `std:map<Point, int>` for the instance counter. Look at the previous comment for implementing `bool operator < (const Point&)`.

Comment: Think about it -- how could it tell if a Point was already in the set? You don't think it compares a new item with every single existing item in the set, do you? That would be horrifically inefficient.